# Discrete math question counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you are trying to get rid of your leftover Halloween chocolate. You decide to make individualized gift bags to give to your lecturers. You have $4$ different types of chocolate to choose from. How many unique gift bags can you create with $10$ items per bag such that each bag has at least one of each type of chocolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have an infinite repetition number of each type of chocolate or at least $7$ pieces of each type of chocolate, then this amounts to the number of positive integral solutions to the equation $$c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=10$$ where $1\leq c_i\leq7$ for each $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. We make the substitution $x_i=c_i-1$ for each $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. This gives us the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6$$ where $0\leq x_i \leq6$ for each $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. The number of non-negative integral solutions to this equation is ${6+4-1\choose 6}={9\choose 6}=84$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You’re looking for the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10\;.$$ this is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the linked article gives you both a formula and a decent explanation and derivation of that formula.

Comment: is the answer should be 286? But I don't really get what is the relationship between these two questions...Thank you.

Comment: @Thom: That’s the number of solutions in non-negative integers; you want the number of solutions in **positive** integers. The idea is that if the types of chocolate are called types $1,2,3$, and $4$, then $x_k$ is the number of chocolates of type $k$ that you put into a bag. Each solution then corresponds to a different distribution of the four types.